# How to change the transparency of an img using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginning to dabble in Jquery and javascript and was looking for some advice please. I have below, the following code which makes a video transparent when I click on the image. However, what code would I need to make the image transparent too, upon click?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

    $("#MinecraftVideo").animate({
                opacity: '0.0'
            });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#picture_on").click(function () {
            $("#MinecraftVideo").animate({
                opacity: '1.0'
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

The image has the id="picture_on"

Many thanks

Comment: Does this not work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/ouLha5nj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `this` selector. This select the element you click on (the image).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#picture_on").click(function () {
        $("#MinecraftVideo").animate({
            opacity: '1.0'
        });
        $(this).animate({opacity: '0'});
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not target the image instead?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#picture_on").click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: '0.5'
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ouLha5nj/1/)